# Repeat same statement in all viewDidLoad functions possible extension file

Tags: ios, swift, function, loops, extension-methods

I want this same statement repeated in all of my projects' `viewDidLoad` functions. I know I can just manually type it in but I am trying to find a way to increase my code speed. I don't know if I can use a extension file in this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myswitchBoolValuefromFirstVc : Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "mySwitch")// this is how you retrieve the bool value

    // to see the value, just print those with conditions. you can use those for your things.
    if myswitchBoolValuefromFirstVc == true {
        print("true")
        rosaryCounterLabel.isHidden = false
    }
    else {
        print("false")
        rosaryCounterLabel.isHidden = true
    }
```

Comment: Extensions can't override existing functionality (or more to the point they shouldn't) - Instead, you would either need to provide an extension which contained a function with the code in it, that you'd need to call from `viewDidLoad` of all you view controllers you wanted to use it, but then you have an issue over instance variables, OR, you could create a custom class which extends from `UIViewController` and that all your own view controllers would inherit from

Comment: @MadProgrammer could you show me a specific example of what you are talking about? Thanks.

Comment: [Inheritance in Swift](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=swift+inheritance&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

If you are prepared to abuse the Objective-C runtime that UIViewController still uses, you can use method swizzling to do what you ask. https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/method-swizzling-in-ios-swift-1f38edaf984f

```
let aClass: AnyClass! = object_getClass(instance)
let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(aClass, #selector(viewDidLoad))
let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(aClass, #selector(newViewDidLoad))
if let originalMethod = originalMethod, let swizzledMethod = swizzledMethod {
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
}
```

but I wouldn't recommend it. You trade between discoverability and repetition. In the case where you control all the code, it is going to be easier to maintain using a solution like subclassing that will still require some changes in every view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Create a "master" view controller.

```
class MasterViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        //"Global" code here
    }

}
```

And then inherit in all your other view controllers

```
class ViewController: MasterViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //controller specific code here
    }

}
```